# Command "f?flagname" doesn't work as expected in radare2

Tags: radare2

```
PS C:\_> r2 -v
radare2 4.3.1 6 @ windows-x86-64 git.4.3.1
commit: 54ac837b5503f10f91e2069ac357791f7a3e635a build: Fri 03/06/2020__15:52:24.93
PS C:\_> r2 --
 -- 99 bugs, take one down pass it around. 100 bugs...
[0x00000000]> f myflag
[0x00000000]> f*
fs *
f myflag 1 0x00000000
[0x00000000]> f?myflag ;expect an output here
[0x00000000]> f?~exists
| f?flagname               check if flag exists or not, See ?? and ?!
```

The command `f?myflag` doesn't print any output as if the flag doesn't exist. Why does it happen?

As a bonus question :), what does `See ?? and ?!` mean?

Comment: Last part probably means: try typing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just doesn't print anything on the the screen but set's internal value. You can be verifie that by looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/75f6f28bb0226b4bd2af9f8f20b2d82202903343/libr/core/cmd_flag.c#L1548).

What it does tell you to do is to run `??` which is actually printing that value as can be seen in the help

```
| ??                               show value of operation
```

Additionally based on the result you can run the operation or not.

```
| ?! [cmd]                         run cmd if $? == 0
| ?? [cmd]                         run cmd if $? != 0

[0x00000000]> f?non-existent-flag
[0x00000000]> ?? ?E exists //<- action is not executed
[0x00000000]> f?myflag
[0x00000000]> ?? ?E exists
 ╭──╮    ╭────────╮
 │ _│    │        │
 │ O O  <  exists │
 │  │╭   │        │
 ││ ││   ╰────────╯
 │└─┘│
 ╰───╯
```